# Accumulating into std::ostream using std::accumulate

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, operator-overloading, ostream

I am trying to use `std::accumulate` to write into `std::ostream` in the `operator<<` (this is just a minimum example, I know this could be implemented much simpler):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A() : v(std::vector<int>()){};
    std::vector<int> v;
    A(std::vector<int> v) : v(v){};
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, A& a);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, A& a) {
// I need something similar to
//    return std::accumulate(a.v.begin(), a.v.end(), "",
                           std::ostream_iterator<int>(stream, " "));
// or:
// return std::accumulate(a.v.begin(), a.v.end(), stream,
                           []()->{});
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> v({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    A a(v);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this operator work?

Comment: This is like "how do I fit a square peg into a round hole".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done:

```
// Using accumulate
std::ostream& out_acc(const std::vector<int>& is, std::ostream& out)
{
    return std::accumulate(is.begin(),
                           is.end(),
                           std::ref(out),
                           [](std::ostream& os, int i) -> std::ostream&
                           { return os << i << ", "; });

}

// Using for_each
std::ostream& out_for(const std::vector<int>& is, std::ostream& out)
{
    std::for_each(is.begin(),
                    is.end(),
                    [&](int i)
                    { out << i << ", "; });
    return out;

}
```

`for_each` is the natural choice, as you don't really care much about the accumulated value.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but OP has a choice of these two only.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `accumulate`, use [`copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, A& a) {
  std::copy(a.v.begin(), a.v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(stream, " "));
}
```

This is actually [one of the examples at the above reference page](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0f8a03656c47fe9f) (though for `std::copy`, not for `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: Those one of the simple solutions. Unfortunately I need to use either `accumulate` or `for_each`.

Comment: So this is a question from some C++ course and you happened to ignore one of the options when posting the question here? Sigh.

Comment: @Rumburak it is from my own project. It will be mich harder to fit for_each to my needs than accumulate, that's why I didn' lt mention it in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You may abuse of `std::accumulate` like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, A& a) {
    return std::accumulate(a.v.begin(), a.v.end(), std::ref(stream),
                           [](std::ostream& stream, int e)
                           { return std::ref(stream << " " << e); });
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc7d59106eb0134)

Comment: Cool. Never underestimate the number of ways to abuse algorithms ;-)

Comment: I found it joyful to further study the possible abuse of `std::accumulate` in this context: would it be possible to use the (appropriate) native `std::ostream` `operator<<` as the `BinaryOp` accumulator? I can get it to work for a custom concrete overload, but I've failed to do the same when attempting to refer to a native overload: See the non-compiling [case C) in the following gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/7f345cc790585f990c17ac99cdf0e24e).

Comment: @dfri: You have 2 issues: member function should be turned in regular functor, and `operator <<` has several overload. Fixed with `std::mem_fn(static_cast<std::ostream& (std::ostream::*)(int)>(&std::ostream::operator<<))` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f7191a3cca0210)

Comment: Ah, I had not seen `std::mem_fn` in use before, and static casting to specify which overload to use was also new to me. Lots of enlightenment, thanks a lot Jarod42!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that `for_each` could be used, too (and accumulate was just mentioned to confuse the Martians):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const A& a) {
  std::for_each(begin(a.v), end(a.v), [](int i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
  return stream;
}
```

Beware: You'll have a trailing space here. You'll need to handle the first or last element differently, if you want to avoid that (for instance by using a counter in the lambda).